# How do I exit TERA?

Tags: tera

I recently started playing TERA. I made a new character, joined a server, then realized that I have absolutely no idea how to exit the game.

Eventually I resorted to force-closing TERA with the Windows Task Manager, but I imagine there has to be a simpler way to to quit the game.

How do I exit TERA after joining a server?

Comment: ...Alt-F4? Have you tried that?

Comment: @Frank I'm able to force quit with Alt-F4, but I was ideally looking for an ingame way to quit

Comment: Been a while playing this game. I forgot what key to enable in-game menu (Ctrl? Alt?) Then there should be a System icon on the rightmost, then you can exit from there.

Answer (score 1):

Unless TERA has changed much since 2015...

1. Press Esc to get the free moving mouse cursor
2. Go the the gear icon in the bottom right of the screen
3. Select "Log Out"
4. Select "Exit Game".

Here's a (moderately annoying) video that corroborates: